# Iterating over custom post type archive returns incorrect first ID

Tags: custom-post-types, archive-template

I'm trying to loop over my custom post type 'services' in a custom archive-services.php file. My loop is:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php echo $post->ID; ?>
        <hr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The first title will return the correct title; but the ID being returned is 'cpt_services,' which is not the ID I need to get the correct feature image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What if you echo `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID`

Comment: I tried that to no avail but did realize how to get it to work by creating a custom query. Not sure if there's a way to do this without, though.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in my case:

I created a custom query and prepended that query to the loop. E.g.:

```
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'services'
);

$services_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        <?php if ( $services_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( $services_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
```

This ended up returning me the ID that I needed to get my first feature image correctly. Unsure if there is a better way to approach this?